# Laravel Dusk Select2 Set Value after data populated from remote URL

Tags: jquery-select2, laravel-dusk

I have a select2 element on a create view that has nothing selected initially.

When entering the select2 element, the select2 element fires off a remote ajax call to an endpoint that returns paginated values.

The list of x amount of values is then displayed on the screen for selection within the select2 element.

How would I populate a selected value (single is fine) during a dusk test?

I've tried things like

type('@item-type-id-select','Figures')->
waitForTextIn('@item-type-id-select', 'Figures')->

But I can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

$output = $browser->script('$("#item_condition_id").select2("trigger","select", {data: { id: "3" }});');